# How to Override a model/ view file at runtime, for a js file combined by requirejs optimizer?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, r.js

Scenario:
Framework used are backbone and require.
I have a main.js which have several dependencies on util, model and view js, which are again inter-dependent. There are cyclic dependencies also.
This main.js has been compiled into a single file using requirejs optimizer.

Problem:
**How to override certain views and models at runtime?**
(I have a single compiled version of main, so i am not talking about excluding the js for models or views at compile time).

At compile time i don't know whether the model/view would be over-ridden. So when i run the optimizer a single js file with all the models and views is created.
I need to override a particular class definition in that single js file, such that i don't modify that file.

**Is there any configuration which will tell 'require' to load the model/view from a separate file rather than that single compiled js file?**

**or is there any way this could be achieved, with minimal changes?**

```
    //models/ - folder

//mymodel.js - filename
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone'
], function($, _, Backbone) {
    var mymodel2 = Backbone.Collection.extend({
       //some code
    });
    return mymodel2;
});

//mymodel2.js - filename
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'mymodel'
], function($, _, Backbone, mymodel) {
    var mymodel2 = Backbone.Collection.extend({
       //some code
    });
    return mymodel2;
});

//views/ - folder


//view1.js - filename
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'runtime/util/logmanager',
    'runtime/util/logger'
], function($, _, Backbone, LogManager, Logger) {
    var view1 = Backbone.View.extend({

        _configure: function(options) {
            //some code
        },

        initialize: function() {
            //some code
        },

        endsWith: function(str, suffix) {
            //some code
        }

    });
    return view1;
});

//like this i have view2.js, view3.js... etc

//Similarly i have util folder with util1.js, util2.js... etc

//main.js
;(function(){

    if (!window.console) window.console = {};
    if (!window.console.log) window.console.log = function () { };
    var paths = {
        jquery: 'libs/jquery/jquery',
        underscore: 'libs/underscore/underscore',
        initializer: 'runtime/initializer/initializer',
        backbone: 'libs/backbone/backbone',
        json2: 'libs/json/json2',
        text: 'libs/require/text',
        jqueryform: 'libs/jqueryform/jqueryform',
        jqueryui: 'libs/jqueryui/jquery-ui',
        slimscroll: 'libs/slimscroll/slimScroll',
        i18next: 'libs/i18next/i18next',
    common: 'libs/commons/common',

    utility1 : 'util/util1',
    utility2 : 'util/util2',
    .
    .
    model2 : 'model/mymodel2',
    .
    .
    .
    view2 : 'view/view1'
};

window.configData = window.configData || {};
window.configData.serverPath = location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host;

require.config({
    paths: paths,
    shim: {
            'underscore': {
                exports: '_'
            },
            'backbone': {
                deps: ['underscore', 'jquery'],
                exports: 'Backbone'
            },
            'i18next': {
                deps: ['jquery', 'json2'],
                exports: 'i18n'
            }
        }
});

require(['router'],
    function(Router) {
        Router.initialize();
    });
})();
```

compiled/ combined file will look something like:

```
    *! jQuery v1.7.1 jquery.com | jquery.org/license */
(//jquery-def file code)(window);

//     Underscore.js 1.3.3
//     (c) 2009-2012 Jeremy Ashkenas, DocumentCloud Inc.
//     Underscore is freely distributable under the MIT license.
//     Portions of Underscore are inspired or borrowed from Prototype,
//     Oliver Steele's Functional, and John Resig's Micro-Templating.
//     For all details and documentation:
//     http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore

(function() {

    //uderscore code
}).call(this);

define("underscore", (function (global) {
    return function () {
        var ret, fn;
        return ret || global._;
    };
}(this)));
.
.
.
all lib definition 
.
.
then depending on the dependencies models, views, utils, routers, definition
.
.
and finally main
;(function(){

    if (!window.console) window.console = {};
    if (!window.console.log) window.console.log = function () { };
    var paths = {
        jquery: 'libs/jquery/jquery-min',
        underscore: 'libs/underscore/underscore',
        initializer: 'runtime/initializer/initializer',
        backbone: 'libs/backbone/backbone',
        json2: 'libs/json/json2',
        text: 'libs/require/text',
        bootstrap: 'libs/bootstrap/bootstrap',
        jqueryform: 'libs/jqueryform/jqueryform',
        jqueryui: 'libs/jqueryui/jquery-ui',
        slimscroll: 'libs/slimscroll/slimScroll',
        i18next: 'libs/i18next/i18next',
        common: 'libs/commons/common',

        utility1 : 'util/util1',
        utility2 : 'util/util2',
        .
        .
        model2 : 'model/mymodel2',
        .
        .
        .
        view2 : 'view/view1'
    };

    window.configData = window.configData || {};
    window.configData.serverPath = location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host;

    require.config({
        paths: paths,
        shim: {
                'underscore': {
                    exports: '_'
                },
                'backbone': {
                    deps: ['underscore', 'jquery'],
                    exports: 'Backbone'
                },
                'i18next': {
                    deps: ['jquery', 'json2'],
                    exports: 'i18n'
                }
            }
    });

    require(['router'],
        function(Router) {
            Router.initialize();
        });
})();


define("main", function(){});
```

Comment: Please revise your question so that it is in the form of a question.

Comment: @Russ Do you need more info?

Comment: not sure exactly what you mean by "override", but I gave it a shot

Comment: I recommend posting code samples

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any configuration which will tell 'require' to load the
>   model/view from a separate file rather than that single compiled js
>   file?

To load a Javascript file using require, you can call it at any time (even after the optimizer has been run), like so:

```
myModule = require('myJavascriptFile');
```

The optimized file isn't designed to be manipulated. Modify your source, then re-optimize.

Also, note: Require does not compile your Javascript.

Comment: No i don't have any exclusive 'require('myJavascriptFile');'... Also i am looking for a solution, which does not require me to re-optimize.

Comment: i am going to provide the optimized file, so if at runtime someone wants to override a component, without touching the compiled file.. he should be able to do that

Comment: why not provide non-optimized files, then let them optimize it after their edits?

Comment: I am exploring an approach which will meet the goal without re-optimize option. the approach you suggested is always the fallback option.

Answer (score 0):

> How to override certain views and models at runtime?

In Javascript, you can reassign variables at any time. Example:

```
var x = 1; // the value of x is 1
x = 2; // the value of x is now 2
```

Similarly, you can override Backbone Models and Views at runtime like so:

```
var myModel = new Backbone.Model({x: 1});// create myModel
myModel = new Backbone.Model({x: 2});// now, myModel is a different model
myModel = "something else entirely";// now, myModel is a string
```

Comment: Ohh, actually at compile time i don't know whether the model/view would be over-ridden. So when i run the optimizer a single js file with all the models and views is created. So i need to override a particular class definition in that single js file, such that i don't need to modify that file.

Comment: JS is an interpreted language, not compiled. Your optimizer does not compile it, it only minifies it.

Comment: 'JS is an interpreted language, not compiled' true. i am using requirejs for dependency management, so when i say compiled, i mean  all the js in model, view, util etc folders are merged into a single file using requirejs optimizer (minification is just one option for it)

Answer (score 0):

You could override `require()` itself and make it look for the module in a directory first before loading it the way that it normally does.

This probably won't be easy to do.